# Why is the unitization of $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ not complete?

Tags: operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, cauchy-sequences, complete-spaces

Consider the space $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ of infinite matrices with only finitely many nonzero entries. This is a pre-C$^*$-algebra, and we can consider its unitization $M_\infty^1(\mathbb{C})$ (the unit will be an infinite matrix with ones on the whole diagonal). From what I understand, this space is not complete (its completion is the C$^*$-algebra $\mathcal{K}$ of compact operators on a separable infinite-dimensional Hilbert space).

Why is $M_\infty^1(\mathbb{C})$ not complete? What is an example of a Cauchy sequence in this space that does not converge?

Comment: The identity operator is not compact!

Comment: @Ruy Oh, I didn't realize that $\mathcal{K}$ was nonunital. Thanks!

Comment: Completeness and Unitisation are two different but compatible pairs of shoes. They can be kept detached:  
The $C^*$-*completion* of $M_\infty(\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathcal{K}=$ the compact operators. Which is a nonunital $C^*$-algebra.

Comment: $\mathcal{K}$'s *unitisation* is $\mathcal K^1 = \mathcal K\oplus\mathbb C\cdot\mathbb 1$ ( = equality/isomorphy of vector spaces). Analogously, one has 
$\,M_\infty^1(\mathbb{C}) = M_\infty(\mathbb{C})\oplus\mathbb C\,$, 
and the $C^*$-completion of $M_\infty^1(\mathbb{C})$ is $\mathcal{K}^1$.
And (+1) ...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider the matrices $x_n$ given by
$$x_n=1\oplus\frac12\oplus\cdots\oplus\frac1{2^{n-1}}\in M_n(C)$$
Then the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is Cauchy in $M_\infty(\mathbb C)$, with
$$\|x_n-x_m\|=\frac{1}{2^{\min\{m,n\}}},$$
but $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ does not converge in $M_\infty(\mathbb C)$ (or its unitization), because any such limit would have $(n,n)$-entry given by $\frac{1}{2^{n-1}}$, hence has infinitely many nonzero entries.

Comment: Perfect! Exactly what I was looking for.